# Adding 2 ascii converted characters using nested loops in Python 3.2

Tags: python, string, unicode, character, ascii

I'm trying to add together strings where each letter has been converted to ASCII and then added together accordingly. So for example, adding together the strings `"goodbye"` `"hello"` I'd like to convert each letter to ascii then add them together like so:

```
103 + 104 (g + h) 
111 + 101 (o + e)
111 + 108 (o + l)
100 + 108 (d + l)
98 + 111  (b + o)
121 + 104 (y + h)
101 + 101 (e + e)
```

In this instance, `"goodbye"` must be interchangeable, i.e. user inputted. This is the code I've generated so far:

```
input1 = input("Enter word: ")
input2 = "goodbye"
l = len(upnumber)
count = 0

for i in (input1):
     x = (ord(i))
     while count <= l:
         for j in (input2):
              y = (ord(j))
              total = (x + y)
              count = count + 1
              print (total)
```

This code doesn't work. It just seems to add the first character of `input1` to every character in `input2`, an innumerate amount of times.

The count is in there as I'd like the loop to stop after each character in `input1` has been added to the loop of `input2`.

Comment: Your code appears to repeat `input2`, but your sample appears to repeat `input1` (the user input) instead. Should the *user input* or the hardcoded key (`goodbye`) be repeated here?

Comment: That's my error there apologies, your answer below fits perfectly, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping over all of `input2` *for each character in `input1`*, because you nested the loops.

Use the [`zip()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) instead to pair up letters:

```
input1 = input("Enter word: ")
input2 = "goodbye"
# make input1 at least as long as input2
while len(input1) <= len(input2):
    input1 += input1
for x, y in zip(input1, input2):
    total = ord(x) + ord(y)
    print(total)
```

where `zip()` will stop iterating once the shortest of the two strings is done. Since `input1` has been extended to repeat until it is at least as long as `input2`, that means you end up processing all characters of `input2`, and no more, unless `input1` was longer to start with.

Instead of manually repeating `input2`, you can also use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle through all characters in `input1` indefinitely:

```
from itertools import cycle

input1 = input("Enter word: ")
input2 = "goodbye"
for x, y in zip(cycle(input1), input2):
    total = ord(x) + ord(y)
    print(total)
```

Demo of the latter approach, with some extra formatting to illustrate what is going on:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> input1 = 'hello'
>>> input2 = "goodbye"
>>> for x, y in zip(cycle(input1), input2):
...     total = ord(x) + ord(y)
...     print('{!r} + {!r} = {:3d} + {:3d} = {:3d}'.format(x, y, ord(x), ord(y), total))
... 
'h' + 'g' = 104 + 103 = 207
'e' + 'o' = 101 + 111 = 212
'l' + 'o' = 108 + 111 = 219
'l' + 'd' = 108 + 100 = 208
'o' + 'b' = 111 +  98 = 209
'h' + 'y' = 104 + 121 = 225
'e' + 'e' = 101 + 101 = 202
```

Comment: Many thanks for your input, do I have your permission to use this in my current university study please?

Comment: @ajh: the whole post is licensed as [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/); it means you already have my permission but you do need to abide by the attribution requirements.